# How do I split a button graphic into a 9 patch?

Tags: 2d, libgdx, graphics

I understand what a nine patch is but I don't understand how to create one with code. I've made an image with a 1-pixel black border, but how do I turn that into a nine patch?

How do I make a nine patch that is not a cube image?

This is what is happening when I run:

```
patch = new NinePatch(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("nineEmpty.9.png")), 4, 4, 13, 28);
```

[image]

[image]

I want it cut like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/NinePatch.html#NinePatch-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion-int-int-int-int-) shows the correct usage of the NinePatch:

```
public NinePatch(TextureRegion region,
             int left,
             int right,
             int top,
             int bottom)

left - Pixels from left edge.
right - Pixels from right edge.
top - Pixels from top edge.
bottom - Pixels from bottom edge.
```

Additionally you can find a tutorial that covers the topic well [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Ninepatches). I suggest you remeasure your graphic and adjust the inputs into the NinePath constructor accordingly. Make sure you don't have any white spaces that could throw off your calculations.